# How can I write a short-hand expression that validates an integer, and returns an integer or a null?

Tags: php, php-7.2, code-readability

I have a need to end up with a variable `$id` that contains either an integer, or a `null` value.

Currently I have this:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$id = filter_var($id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT); //false or integer
if (!$id)
    $id = null;
```

Is there a more concise way to write this?  I am looking to consolidate 3 statements into one line if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like: `$id = $id ?: null;`

**EDIT:**
Taking @treyBake's suggestion, your code block can be turned into a single line using this:
`$id = filter_var($_POST['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) ?: null;`

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a `FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE`:

```
$id = filter_var($_POST['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
```